# Simpsons episode where "Springfield" is mentioned on a train

Tags: identify-this-episode, the-simpsons

I can't remember which episode of The Simpsons was this scene from:

A man is running behind a train (maybe something he wants is on the train), and he can't keep up with it, so he shouts asking one of the passengers on the train: where is this train going to?
The passenger says: Springfield.
The man says: yeah, but which state?
To which the passengers is baffled or shows an expression as if he just heard a stupid question.
The train fades away in distance, and the man never gets an answer. 
But I think he finally gets there.

Can't remember the rest of the plot or what the man was after.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like [Burns Baby Burns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burns,_Baby_Burns) from season 8. From [this page](http://simpsons.wikia.com/wiki/Springfield's_State):

> Montgomery Burns's long lost son recognizes his father on a train but is unable to board it before it moves away. He asks an attendant standing on the final carriage where it is going and is told "Springfield". The son says: "Yeah, but what state?" The guard's reply is almost inaudible, but ends in the syllable "-aska". This suggests that Springfield could be in Nebraska or Alaska.